# Drain to a reservior when water height is higher then the drainage

Tags: water, drainage, pump, gardening

I have a reservior made from a 220litre plastic drum which is about 1.2 meters tall. i have a sump to irrigate my garden in the drum and it pumps out the top through a pipe to my garden tray which sits at around 300mm from the ground. it then drains out the bottom via a 19mm hole in the bottom of the tray. is there a way to return the drainage to the reserviour without using another drainage bucket and pump? If not then what would be a suitable setup here?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram would be really helpful here.

Comment: I wonder if you could water by siphoning, and use the sump to refill the top tank. Siphoning type systems work well in situations where you have enough head space.

Answer (score 3):

The only feasible way to recycle the drainage water from the tray without an additional pump is to place the tray at a level above the top of the reservior and let the water flow by force of gravity back into the tank.